# How do I implement a word-by-word navigator for a flowdocument?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a word-by-word navigator such that I can use Right and Left arrow key to move by 1 word per each key strike. The selecting word will have a custom color to mark that it is being selected. This is for the purpose of word by word manipulation feature.

I plan to manipulate `FlowDocument` content by encapsulating the selecting word with `<Span Name="selected" Foreground="color">`. However, I believe that `FlowDocument` only allow me to extract plain text, not xaml sources. On the other hand, I can't find any function that will allow me to encapsulate existing text with tag element such as `<Span>`.

Otherwise, I could only think if clearing everything up, then rewrite the whole thing with correct `<Span>` position. However, this event is expected to happen frequently (Everytime I press Right or Left arrow key).

Is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: "FlowDocument only allow me to extract plain text, not xaml sources", this might be incorrect, you can extract rich info from a flow doc object.

Comment: Can you please point me out how to do that? The only examples I found are one that shows how to extract plain text.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981884/how-can-i-get-a-textpointer-from-a-mouse-click-in-a-flowdocument